# Name of Bi - Functor type class with one contravariant and one covariant parameter

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, scala-cats

I'm looking to see if there is a standard typeclass for a Bi-Functor that has one Contravariant parameter and one Covariant parameter.

punching the signature `(c -> a) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d` results in nothing that matches.

Basically in Scala I'm looking to do:

```
trait CoContraBiFunctor[F[_, _]] {
  def ccmap[A, B, C, D](fab: F[A, B])(f: C => A)(g: B => D): F[C, D]
}

implicit val ccFunction: CoContraBiFunctor[Function1] = new CoContraBiFunctor[Function] {
  override def ccmap[A, B, C, D](fab: Function[A, B])(f: C => A)(g: B => D): Function[C, D] = new Function[C, D] {
    override def apply(c: C): D = g(fab(f(c)))
  }
}
```

Anyone have an idea?  I definitely am not the first person to look for this.

Comment: Where did you "punch the signature"?  [I found it that way](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(c%20-%3E%20a)%20-%3E%20(b%20-%3E%20d)%20-%3E%20f%20a%20b%20-%3E%20f%20c%20d).  Fun fact, there are [three](http://haskell.org/hoogle) [different](https://hoogle.haskell.org) [hoogles](https://www.stackage.org/package/hoogle) and they all give different results!  Only `hoogle.haskell.org` gives a result for your query. :-/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called a *profunctor*! It is a [very useful type of bifunctor](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/07/profunctors-in-haskell.html) that shows up all over the place (for example, [in the construction of lenses](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1703/1703.10857.pdf))! In Haskell it is available as `Data.Profunctor` in the `profunctors` package. I am not a Scala person but it looks like it is [available](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/arrow/Profunctor.html) in `cats` as well.

Comment: Thank you I knew I had heard it before and I just couldn't remember

Comment: Re profuctorial lenses: Some useful links are http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-18-glassery.html (for pure profunctor lenses) as well as https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-4 and https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-5 (for van Laarhoven lenses). The diagrams in the last one in particular is what made profunctors 'click' for me, but they're all fascinating reads.